# Is a "dozen donuts" a singular or plural subject?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, quantifiers

which is correct?  How much IS a dozen of donuts?  OR How much are a dozen of donuts?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. The question lined in the comment addresses *dozen* specifically. We also have a search function on this site. I encourage you to take the site tour and visit the help center for guidance on how to use this site.

Answer (score 0):

In American English, the most understood form would be 'is'--and don't use the word 'of':

> How much is a dozen donuts?

If you say 'are', you're likely to receive a response of 'twelve donuts.'

Answer (score 0):

Several points:

1) The standard term is "a dozen donuts" (not "a dozen **of** donuts").

2) The question "How much is a dozen donuts?" could mean one of two things:

a) How many donuts make up a dozen?

b) What does a dozen donuts cost?

3) American English usage is fussier than British English with regard to number agreement between subject and verb. In British English, both forms of your query sentence would be acceptable (provided the 'of' is omitted), whereas American English usage would usually prescribe "How much is a dozen donuts?"

Comment: @Flimzy Whilst I agree with you that ambiguity is possible, with me  it would be if you used *is*. But I am British and regularly use *are* where an American might use *is* - *Norwich are playing Sheffield Wednesday at the week-end*. But I also spell them *doughnuts*.

Comment: *Comments removed* This was getting a little heated. Please refrain from discussing the merits of an answer in comments. Vote; and explain a vote if you like.

Answer (score -1):

The subject is plural, but you don't need the preposition. The correct form would be:

> How much are a dozen doughnuts?

Comment: Please support your answer with sources. That makes your answer stronger, and more likely to be viewed as correct. Otherwise it's only opinion. The [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) will give you guidance on how to use this site.

Comment: Except that in the donut (and egg) trade, "a dozen" is a common unit of measure, just the same way as a gallon of milk, a bushel of apples, a hand of bananas, or a bag of peanuts. If you would ask "how much is a bag of peanuts", or "how much is a gallon of milk", one would by extension ask, "how much is a dozen donuts".